# How can I download files in specific days? [ Kotlin Android Development ]

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduled-tasks, schedule

What is a safe and greater method to execute tasks ( in my case call a function ) in specific time ( in my case every two days ) ?

The function retrieves data from the Web. My target is update the data in app whenever it changes on the webserver.

Thanks, good job!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Answer (score 1):

1- If you don't need to be exact about time, you need to use WorkManager and set periodic work request

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

```
fun CreateWorkRequest()
{
  val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

val duration = 2*24*60*60*1000L //2 days in mili second

        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<AutoBackUpWorker>(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setInitialDelay(duration/2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addTag("diaryBackUpWork")
                .build()

        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("backupwork", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, autoBackUpRequest)
}
```

Worker Class:

```
    class RequestedWorker(val appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, workerParams)
    
{
    override fun doWork()
    {
    
    }
}
```

2- If you need to be exact about time (like at 8pm everyday) you need to use Alarm Manager

3- In your case the best choice is implementing DownloadManager for download request in the doWork() method